# domain of definition of a semilinear PDE $x∂_xz + y∂_yz = −z^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, characteristics, linear-pde

I'm reading [page 55](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/30048/mod_resource/content/16/DE1notes22-11-09.pdf#page=55) of a differential equation text. §3.5 Domain of definition gives an example

> As a simple example which illustrates this behaviour you can consider the equation
> $$
> x∂_xz + y∂_yz = −z^2
> $$
> with prescribed data of $z(x, y) = α ∈\Bbb R$ for on $\{(x, y) : x + y = 1, x ∈ [0, 1]\}$.

**My working:**

Introduce a parameter $s$ for the data, say $γ(s) = (s,1-s,\alpha)$, for $0 ≤ s ≤ 1$, and
then solve the characteristic equations with this as data at $t = 0$:
\begin{align}
x&=s \exp (t)\\
y&=(1-s) \exp (t)\\
z&=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\alpha }+t}\quad(\alpha\ne0)\end{align}
From the first two equations $t=\log(x+y)$,
plugging in the third equation,
$$z=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\alpha }+\log(x+y)}$$
which is singular on $x+y=\exp(-1/\alpha)$.

The characteristic projections are rays through the origin in the first quadrant, so

- for $α=0$:
  the solution is $z=0$, defined on $\{(x,y):x>0, y>0\}$
- for $α>0$: domain of definition is
  $\{(x,y):x>0, y>0 ,\text{ and }x+y>\exp(-1/α)\}$
- for $α<0$: domain of definition is
  $\{(x,y):x>0, y>0 ,\text{ and }x+y<\exp(-1/α)\}$

Could you check if my solution contains any error? Thanks!